# Monotouch, create a jpg from a UIImageView that has a UIlabel attached

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, uiimageview, uilabel, jpeg

Using Monotouch, I have a UIImageView with some UIlabels attached to him, basically it's an image with some text overlying it, like a postcard. I want to take this image and text and create a jpg/png that is a combination of both.

I have no idea how to do so. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craig Dunn has a post that outlines how to [programatically do a screen capture](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/10/monotouch-screen-capture-in-c-code.html).  It's older, but I think it will still work.

The core idea is

```
   UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(View.Frame.Size); 
   var ctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
   if (ctx != null)
   {
      View.Layer.RenderInContext(ctx);
      UIImage img = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
      UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Jason but I tried it already. But it's not good since quality of the screen shoot is not very good.

Comment: What do you mean?  I believe that the capture should be the same resolution as your display.